# Avoiding cPickle in Ipython's parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython, pickle

I have some code that I have paralleled successfully in the sense that it gets an answer, but it is still kind of slow. Using cProfile.run(), I found that 121 seconds (57% of total time) were spent in cPickle.dumps despite a per call time of .003. I don't use this function anywhere else, so it must be occurring due to ipython's parallel.

The way my code works is it does some serial stuff, then runs many simulations in parallel. Then some serial stuff, then a simulation in parallel. It has to repeat this many, many times. Each simulation requires a very large dictionary that I pull in from a module I wrote. I believe this is what is getting pickled many times and slowing the program down.

Is there a way to push a large dictionary to the engines in such a way that it stays there permanently? I think it's getting physically pushed every time I call the parallel function.

Comment: if you don't need the entire dictionary every time you call the function, you should store the key-value pairs individually, so you only load/dump what you need (see `klepto` for how you might do this).  Also, if you want to avoid `cPickle`, you can use either `dill` or `cloudpickle` as an alternate serializer in `ipython.parallel`.

Comment: It's basically impossible for me to know which parts of the dictionary I'll need before hand. It depends on what the simulation produces, which is random.

It's possible that this is also an issue with function seralization overall. It's hard to tell--all I know is pickle.dumps get's called very frequently.

I will try to use use_dill and see if theres a performance enhancement. Just stumbled upon that functionality a few minutes ago.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know what key-value pairs you need ahead of time, just a better way to store/retrieve the entries.  For example, if the values are array data, a collection of memmapped files can work, or the values are floats, pickling works well.  If the dict is huge, but the entries are not all needed, the solution should be to store the entries so you can look up what's needed when it's needed (again, see `klepto` which provides a `dict` interface to tabular data on disk or database).  It's hard to say more without knowing what your data looks like.